# Xcode 5.1 crashes when I try and use SDL

Tags: xcode5.1

Updated Xcode recently to 5.1 and SDL just does not work! Please watch the video so that you may understand.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6epZLlSrr5c

Comment: This video is private. Sorry about that.

Comment: Loki Clock - It's public now, I am the one to be sorry.

Comment: This question is way too broad. When you SDL just does not work, please be more specific. If you have any code that is relevant to the situation, please also post that in your question.

Comment: It looks like you were using build & run, and when it tried to run it crashed XCode, is that right?

Comment: Try building in release mode and running the executable from Finder.

Comment: The code is simply a test code. And the same thing happens for other test codes or any code that uses SDL. For a normal cout <<< ("Hello world") it works fine. But when I include SDL and use a code from that file it crashes when I run it. I don't build & run I just run on Mac.

Comment: I can't build it in release mode either for some reason :S

Comment: It's always running on Mac. Does your application open automatically once it's done building? If so, you have to switch build modes. If not, do you mean XCode won't build a project set to build in release mode, or the same problem occurs when you try and launch an executable compiled in release mode? This identifies whether XCode is crashing or your application is crashing.